# Looking for examples of "thank you" e-mail designs

Tags: website-design

I've been tasked with creating "thank you for attending" HTML e-mails/graphics for a number of events. I've already done a few, but they all need to look distinct and I'm running out of ideas. Does anyone know of a gallery that shows this type of design, or of any outstanding examples?

Answer (score 2):

Why not go uber simple and make it about the actual copy rather than the design as such. You would be surprised how much it affects things.

It really depends of course, on what you want people to do with it.

I have often done very complicated and beautiful thank you emails.

But I have found that doing it really simple is interesting in itself.

For instance when people sign up to my service [WeekendHacker](http://www.weekendhacker.net) I send a really simple mail back saying:

> **Hey thanks for signing up**
>
> *You will have to include: Name, Project description and what skills
>   you are looking for. If you want to
>   keep your idea tight then you should
>   at least specify the kind of tasks you
>   are looking for You'll only receive
>   one mail a day, curated; if you don't
>   want to receive mails any more, just
>   mail me. Have fun!*

That's just my five cents.

Comment: Actually, "uber simple" was what they were doing before I got involved. They decided they didn't like simple, so they asked me to do something. My specific assignment is to take the copy given to me and figure out a way to make it "pop" graphically. If I send back plain text or text with just minimal decoration my boss will tell me I haven't done my job.

Comment: heh yeah I see what you are saying :)

Answer (score 1):

I always enjoy looking through [these galleries at Mail Chimp](http://mailchimp.com/features/email-template-gallery/), which happens to be a pretty good service also.

Comment: This page is now broken.

Answer (score 1):

Campaign Monitor has some great examples too:

http://www.campaignmonitor.com/templates/